# HttpClient unable to post XML server returns Syntactically Incorrect Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, httpclient

Is there any working example for posting XML/json to REST service using `HttpClient`? I have tried but server returned error request was syntactically incorrect.

```
  // my functions 
public T Post<T>(string method, string data)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var requestMessage = GetHttpRequestMessage<string>(data);

        var result = httpClient.PostAsync(_endpoint + method, requestMessage.Content).Result;

        return result.Content.ReadAsync<T>().Result;
    }
}

protected HttpRequestMessage GetHttpRequestMessage<T>(T data, bool isJsonContent = false)
{
    var msg = new HttpRequestMessage
                  {
                      Content =
                          isJsonContent
                              ? new ObjectContent<T>(data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { })
                              : new ObjectContent<T>(data, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter() { })
                  };
    return msg;
}
```

Is there any better way to use `HttpClient` ?

Comment: Where is the error happening? The first step is probably to use Fiddler to inspect your message and see what doesn't look right. Also, instead of using HttpClient, I would recommend looking into something like RestSharp (available on NuGet) to make this easier.

Comment: What exception do you get? Do you have access to debug the server application? What does the data structure look like?

"server returned error request was syntactically incorrect." indicates that Tim's approach on using a sniffer to see what the data looks like probably will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for reply. The problem occurs when i post it. The API server is running Spring. and when it is validating the request data than it throws the exception that request was syntactically incorrect. But when i post the same thing from Postman (chrome extension) it works fine.